# what's the meaning of the categories in the corpus reuters of NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I suffered from problems, when doing text topic classification.

I got the data in NLTK "reuters" corpus..

However when I try "reuters.categories()"

the result is

['acq', 'alum', 'barley', 'bop', 'carcass', 'castor-oil', 'cocoa', 'coconut', 'coconut-oil', 'coffee', 'copper', 'copra-cake', 'corn', 'cotton', 'cotton-oil', 'cpi', 'cpu', 'crude', 'dfl', 'dlr', 'dmk', 'earn', 'fuel', 'gas', 'gnp', 'gold', 'grain', 'groundnut', 'groundnut-oil', 'heat', 'hog', 'housing', 'income', 'instal-debt', 'interest', 'ipi', 'iron-steel', 'jet', 'jobs', 'l-cattle', 'lead', 'lei', 'lin-oil', 'livestock', 'lumber', 'meal-feed', 'money-fx', 'money-supply', 'naphtha', 'nat-gas', 'nickel', 'nkr', 'nzdlr', 'oat', 'oilseed', 'orange', 'palladium', 'palm-oil', 'palmkernel', 'pet-chem', 'platinum', 'potato', 'propane', 'rand', 'rape-oil', 'rapeseed', 'reserves', 'retail', 'rice', 'rubber', 'rye', 'ship', 'silver', 'sorghum', 'soy-meal', 'soy-oil', 'soybean', 'strategic-metal', 'sugar', 'sun-meal', 'sun-oil', 'sunseed', 'tea', 'tin', 'trade', 'veg-oil', 'wheat', 'wpi', 'yen', 'zinc']

I almost don't know what each one means, can I find some explanations ?

Answer (score 3):

Information about the Reuters corpus in `NLTK` corpus API:

- The Reuters-21578 "ApteMod" corpus is built for **text classification**.
- ApteMod is a collection of 10,788 documents from the Reuters
  financial newswire service
- In the ApteMod corpus, **each document belongs to one or more categories**. There are 90 categories in the corpus.

The mapping of the fileids to the categories can be found in `~/nltk_data/corpora/reuters/cats.txt`

```
from os.path import expanduser
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import reuters

home = expanduser("~")
id2cat = defaultdict(list)

for line in open(home+'/nltk_data/corpora/reuters/cats.txt','r'):
    fid, _, cats = line.partition(' ')
    id2cat[fid] = cats.split()

for fileid in reuters.fileids():
    for sent in reuters.sents(fileid):
        print id2cat[fileid], sent
```

[out]:

```
['trade'] ['ASIAN', 'EXPORTERS', 'FEAR', 'DAMAGE', 'FROM', 'U', '.', 'S', '.-', 'JAPAN', 'RIFT', 'Mounting', 'trade', 'friction', 'between', 'the', 'U', '.', 'S', '.', 'And', 'Japan', 'has', 'raised', 'fears', 'among', 'many', 'of', 'Asia', "'", 's', 'exporting', 'nations', 'that', 'the', 'row', 'could', 'inflict', 'far', '-', 'reaching', 'economic', 'damage', ',', 'businessmen', 'and', 'officials', 'said', '.']
...
```

You can find the information about the categories from this file:`~/nltk_data/corpora/reuters/README`:

> ```
>   The Reuters-21578 benchmark corpus, ApteMod version
> ```
>
> This is a publically available version of the well-known Reuters-21578
>   "ApteMod" corpus for text categorization.  It has been used in
>   publications like these:
>
> - Yiming Yang and X. Liu. "A re-examination of text categorization
>     methods".  1999.  Proceedings of 22nd Annual International SIGIR.
>     http://citeseer.nj.nec.com/yang99reexamination.html
> - Thorsten Joachims. "Text categorization with support vector
>     machines: learning with many relevant features".  1998. Proceedings
>     of ECML-98, 10th European Conference on Machine Learning.
>     http://citeseer.nj.nec.com/joachims98text.html
>
> ApteMod is a collection of 10,788 documents from the Reuters financial
>   newswire service, partitioned into a training set with 7769 documents
>   and a test set with 3019 documents.  The total size of the corpus is
>   about 43 MB.  It is also available for download from
>   http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/reuters21578/reuters21578.html ,
>   which includes a more extensive history of the data revisions.
>
> The distribution of categories in the ApteMod corpus is highly skewed,
>   with 36.7% of the documents in the most common category, and only
>   0.0185% (2 documents) in each of the five least common categories. In fact, the original data source is even more skewed---in creating the
>   corpus, any categories that did not contain at least one document in
>   the training set and one document in the test set were removed from
>   the corpus by its original creator.
>
> In the ApteMod corpus, each document belongs to one or more
>   categories.  There are 90 categories in the corpus.  The average
>   number of categories per document is 1.235, and the average number of
>   documents per category is about 148, or 1.37% of the corpus.
>
> -Ken Williams   ken@mathforum.org
>
> ```
>      Copyright & Notification
> ```
>
> (extracted from the README at the UCI address above)
>
> The copyright for the text of newswire articles and Reuters
>   annotations in the Reuters-21578 collection resides with Reuters Ltd.
>   Reuters Ltd. and Carnegie Group, Inc. have agreed to allow the free
>   distribution of this data *for research purposes only*.
>
> If you publish results based on this data set, please acknowledge its
>   use, refer to the data set by the name "Reuters-21578, Distribution
>   1.0", and inform your readers of the current location of the data set (see "Availability & Questions").

Comment: If you follow the link http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/reuters21578/reuters21578.html it says that the ModApté split has 12902 entries, not 10788.  Why this difference?

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's because of tokenization/file reading problems.

Comment: Ah its because there is a difference between ApteMod and ModApte.  The ApteMod is the same as the R(90) subset of the ModApte.  Confusing because a lot of literature describes ModApte as having 10788 documents, which is strictly speaking not true.  But difficult when that subset is named ApteMod.